# Using LINQ to construct a list C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, group-by, using

```
 ProductCategory = "A"
 Public Class ProdCat
 {
     public   int productId,
     public string  productCategory
}
```

I have a list like this

```
List<ProdCat> ProdCatList = new List<ProdCat>();
ProdCatList.Add( new ProdCat{ productId= 1, productCategory= "A" } );
ProdCatList.Add( new ProdCat{ productId= 2, productCategory= "B" } );
ProdCatList.Add( new ProdCat{ productId= 3, productCategory= "A" } );
ProdCatList.Add( new ProdCat{ productId= 4, productCategory= "C" } );
ProdCatList.Add( new ProdCat{ productId= 5, productCategory = "A" } );
ProdCatList.Add( new ProdCat{ productId = 6, productCategory= "B" } );
```

I need to come up with a list like this. Please note ProductCatList is a list and it has two properties, Namely Product Category which is a sting and productIds which is another list in ProductCatList

```
ProductCatList
     ProductCategory = "A"
         productId = 1
         productId = 3
         productId = 5
   ProductCategory = "B"
         productId = 2
         productId = 6
   ProductCategory = "C"
         productId = 4
```

Class Implementation would be like below

```
Public Class ProductCatGroup
{
   string      ProductCategory ,
   IList <int> ProdcutId 

}
```

How can i achieve something like above using LINQ

---

I have two classes as below

```
 public class product
            {
    
                public int productId { get; set; }
                public string productName { get; set; }
            }
    
            public class ProductCat
            {
    
    
                public int productId { get; set; }
                public string productName { get; set; }
                public int productCatId { get; set; }
                public string ProductCatName { get; set; }
            }
```

The list is as below

```
   List<ProdCat> ProdCatList = new List<ProdCat>();
    ProdCatList.Add( new ProdCat{ productId= 1, productCatId = "1", productName="PA", ProductCatName = "PC1"});
    ProdCatList.Add( new ProdCat{ productId= 2, productCatId = "2", productName="PB", ProductCatName = "PC2"});
    ProdCatList.Add( new ProdCat{ productId= 3, productCatId = "2", productName="PC", ProductCatName = "PC2"});
    ProdCatList.Add( new ProdCat{ productId= 4, productCatId = "1", productName="PD", ProductCatName = "PC1"});
    ProdCatList.Add( new ProdCat{ productId= 5, productCatId = "1", productName="PE", ProductCatName = "PC1"});
```

And I need to come up with something like below

```
 ProductCatGroup
      productCatId = "1"
      ProductCatName = "PC1"
           productId = 1
           productName = "PA"
           productId = 4
           productName = "PD"
           productId = 5
           productName = "PE"
      productCatId = "2"
      ProductCatName = "PC2"
             productId = 2
             productName = "PB"
             productId = 3
             productName = "PC"
```

Class implementation is as below

```
public class ProductCatGroup
{
           public int productCatId { get; set; }
            public int productCatName{ get; set; }
            public IList<Product> ProductList = new List<Product>();

}
```

I think this is much clear now

Comment: What's with all the `enter code here`?

Comment: `Public` and `Class` need to be lowercase.

Comment: I don't even know what you are asking here, and why would LINQ be a requirement?

Comment: You have just asked this question....

Comment: yes but it was not much clear...I have re-posted this in much clear way..please help me

Comment: @Jamiec: This is the older question so the other would be the duplicate.

Comment: I flagged the question as not constructive..it doesn't let me to delete it

Comment: You should edit your original question, not post a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var grouped = ProductCatList.GroupBy(g => new{g.productCatId,g.productCatName})
                     .Select(g => new ProductCatGroup()
                                  {
                                      productCatId = g.Key.productCatId,
                                      productCatName = g.Key.productCatName,
                                      ProductList = g.Select(p => new Prroduct()
                                                    {
                                                         productid = p.productId,
                                                         productName = p.productName
                                                     }
                                  });
```

Comment: This will serve my purpose .... Thank you so much ...It saved me writing a complex foreach loop.. Thanks for all the others as well for trying to help me

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize a `ProductCatGroup` like this:

```
        ProductCatGroup g = new ProductCatGroup
        {
            ProductCategory = "A",
            ProductID = (new int[] { 1, 3, 5 }).ToList()
        };
```

You can generate a list of `ProductCatGroup`s from your example list using `GroupBy` like this:

```
        IEnumerable<ProductCatGroup> groups = ProdCatList
            .GroupBy(item => item.productCategory)
            .Select(g => new ProductCatGroup
            {
                ProductCategory = g.Key,
                ProductID = g.Select(x => x.productId).ToList()
            });
```

Comment: I want to come up with a list which has ProductCatergory and product Ids as list

Answer (score 0):

Find the below code if it helps you

```
public class ProdCat
{
    public int productId;
    public string productCategory;
}

public class ProductCatGroup
{
    public string ProductCategory;
    public IList<int> ProdcutId;

}
public Form1()
{
    List<ProdCat> ProdCatList = new List<ProdCat>();
    ProdCatList.Add(new ProdCat { productId = 1, productCategory = "A" });
    ProdCatList.Add(new ProdCat { productId = 2, productCategory = "B" });
    ProdCatList.Add(new ProdCat { productId = 3, productCategory = "A" });
    ProdCatList.Add(new ProdCat { productId = 4, productCategory = "C" });
    ProdCatList.Add(new ProdCat { productId = 5, productCategory = "A" });
    ProdCatList.Add(new ProdCat { productId = 6, productCategory = "B" });

    var productCatList = from pc in ProdCatList
        group pc by pc.productCategory into pcGroup
        select new ProductCatGroup { ProductCategory = pcGroup.Key, ProdcutId = pcGroup.Select(x => x.productId).ToList() }; 
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var grouped = ProductCatList.GroupBy(g => g.ProductCategory )
                 .Select(g => new ProductCatGroup()
                              {
                                  ProductCategory = g.Key,
                                  ProductList = g.Select(p =>  p.productId)
                                                 .ToList()
                              });
```